# Chapter 2 Section 2 in Macdonald's Symmetric Functions and Hall Polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-functions, hall-algebras

Throughout this post $R$ denotes a discrete valuation ring with residue field $R/\frak{m}$ being finite. I'm reading Macdonald's exposition on the Hall Algebra on page 183 and trying to make sense of it. Let $H(R)$ denote the Hall Algebra.

I can understand how he constructs it using a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module on a basis $\mathcal{B} = \{b_{\lambda} \hspace{2pt} | \hspace{2pt} \lambda \textrm{ is a partition} \}$ as well as the multiplication operation that is defined on the basis elements and extended the natural way which gives it the commutative ring structure.

He then goes on to make the claim (which he labels as 2.3) that $H(R)$ is generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra by the set $X = \{u_{(1^{r})} \hspace{2pt} | \hspace{2pt} r \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}\}$ and I'm quite confused by how he is trying to prove this. The proof goes as follows.

Pick a partition $\lambda$ (which corresponds to an element $b_{\lambda} \in \mathcal{B}$) and consider $\lambda^{*} = (\lambda^{*}_{1}, \lambda^{*}_{2}, ... , \lambda^{*}_{s})$ where $\lambda^{*}$ is the conjugate partition of $\lambda$. He makes use of the product

\begin{align*}
u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{1}})} \cdot u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{2}})} \cdot ... \cdot u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{s}})}
\end{align*}
By definition of multiplication in $H(R)$, we should be getting

\begin{align*}
 u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{1}})} \cdot u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{2}})} \cdot ... \cdot u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{s}})} = \displaystyle \sum_{\mu \in \mathcal{B}} G^{\mu}_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{1}}) (1^{\lambda^{*}_{2}})...(1^{\lambda^{*}_{s}})}(R)b_{\mu}
\end{align*}

He instead writes this as

\begin{align*}
 u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{1}})} \cdot u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{2}})} \cdot ... \cdot u_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{s}})} = \displaystyle \sum_{\mu \in \mathcal{B}} a_{\lambda \mu}b_{\mu}
\end{align*}

I would guess that $a_{\lambda \mu} = G^{\mu}_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{1}}) (1^{\lambda^{*}_{2}})...(1^{\lambda^{*}_{s}})}(R)$ for each $\mu$ and the definition of $G^{\mu}_{(1^{\lambda^{*}_{1}}) (1^{\lambda^{*}_{2}})...(1^{\lambda^{*}_{s}})}(R)$ is exactly as what is stated on the top of page 183. Assuming this guess is correct I can follow the rest of the argument up to the point when he says that non-zero $a_{\lambda \mu}$ are contributed only when $\mu^{*} \geq \lambda^{*}$ and this is equivalent to $\mu \leq \lambda$. Furthermore $a_{\lambda \lambda} = 1$.

He then mysteriously says that "$a_{\lambda \mu}$ is a strictly upper unitrianglular matrix" and gives the reference to Chapter 1 Section 6 where he talks about matrices whose columns and rows are indexed by a partition of $n$ using the ordering.

Here is my source of confusion.

1. For the general strategy of the proof, is he trying to to show each basis element $b_{\lambda}$ can be written as a polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ using the elements of $X$?
2. Why is $a_{\lambda\mu}$ a matrix in the sense of Chapter 1 Section 6 given that $\lambda$ is fixed and not varying and that we are only running over $\mu$. Furthermore if it is indeed a matrix in the sense of Chapter 1 Section 6, then what is the $n$ such that this matrix's rows and columns are being indexed?

I think I should be able to follow the proof once I can get some clarity on this. As usual any help is greatly appreciated and apologies for the very long post as I wanted to make the question as clear as possible.

Comment: I can offer a general piece of advice, from when I took a topics course about this material.  We found that a lot of Macdonald's (basically combinatorial) arguments were very difficult to understand without drawing out a bunch of increasingly complicated Young diagrams.  However, after looking at those explicit examples, the seemingly opaque reasoning  would often "click," making it suddenly obvious why something was true